# How to combine a SIZE OF operator in ASN with another variable?

Tags: c++, c, networking, network-programming, asn.1

I have an ASN defnition like this:

`TEST-ME ::=        SEQUENCE (SIZE (1..maxUMS)) OF UMStoADD`

which yields

a struct like this

`struct {
           TEST-ME-type TestMe[11]
}`

Now I want to introduce a variable in `TEST-ME` which can yield a struct like this

`struct {
           TEST-ME-type TestMe[11];
           My_Bool_type variable;
}`

I have to now tried this:

```
`TEST-ME ::=        SEQUENCE {

(SIZE (1..maxUMS)) OF UMStoADD, 
My_Bool_type  variable}`
```

But this does not work. How do I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

```
TEST-ME ::= SEQUENCE {
    field1 SEQUENCE (SIZE (1..maxUMS)) OF UMStoADD, 
    filed2 My_Bool_type  
}
```